# How to diagonalize the following perturbation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory, matrix-elements

Consider an infinite cubic well:
$V(x,y,z)=0$ for $0<x<L, 0<y<L, 0<z<L$

and $V=\infty$ otherwise

The eigenstates of this system are given by:
$$\Psi(x,y,z)=\bigg(\frac{2}{L}\bigg)^{\frac{3}{2}} \sin(n\pi x/L)\sin(n\pi y/L)\sin(n\pi z/L)$$

Now I add a perturbation of the form:
$$\hat H_p=V_0L^3\delta(x-L/4)\delta(y-3L/4)\delta(z-L/4)$$
This is simply a Dirac delta at a single point $(L/4, 3L/4, L/4)$.

If the perturbation were a matrix I could easily find the degenerate sub-space and then diagonalize it to get the first order energies but I do not know how one finds the subspace of a perturbation given as a function. I could calculate the matrix of this perturbation as $\langle \psi_n(x,y,z)|\hat H_p|\psi_m(x,y,z)_n\rangle$ but it would be infinite-dimensional.

I want to know how one identifies the degenerate subspace and then diagonalizes it for the perturbation like the one given above.

Comment: The eigenstates should allow different $n$'s for $x/y/z$ directions. Then you will get degenerate subspace.

Comment: Yes. I have reached that part. The eigenvalues repeat for certain $ns$. Let's say it repeats for $n=1,5,10.. $and so on. Now how do I use this information to write out and diagonalize the degenerate subspace. Do I calculate $\langle \psi_n|H_p| \psi_n\rangle$ for all these n's individually to get the subspace?

Comment: I think we are not talking about the same thing. What I meant is that the eigenfunction should be $\sin\frac{n_x x}{L}\sin\frac{n_y y}{L}\sin\frac{n_z z}{L}$, where $n_x, n_y, n_z$ are independent positive integers. The energy eigenvalue should be proportional to $n_x^2+n_y^2+n_z^2$. So the lowest energy is $(n_x,n_y,n_z)=(1,1,1)$. The first excited state is now 3-fold degenerate: $(n_x,n_y,n_z)=(2,1,1), (1,2,1), (1,1,2)$. Then you calcualte the projection of $H_p$ in this subspace.